# Can one VSTS project be mapped to different local workspaces?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfvc

I have a class library project to be shared by two different solutions in Visual Studio 2017. The solutions are mapped in two different workspaces. I cannot find a way to get the shared project under source control in both solutions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have two separate Team Projects, each with its own TFVC repository. Underneath one of those Team Projects (say, TPA), you have a common library that you'd like to share with a solution located in Team Project B (TPB).

You can't do what you're asking to do -- even if you could do it, you shouldn't. You don't want to fork the source code and maintain two copies of it. What you want to do is one of the following:

1. Map a single workspace containing all of the Team Projects and use relative 
   paths for references. This isn't great, ideally each Team Project is considered a totally separate entity.
2. Put everything in a single Team Project and maintain a single workspace for everything.
3. Turn the shared component into a NuGet package and use a [Package Management feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/overview?view=vsts). Each consumer of the shared component can then reference a common NuGet package.

I'd say #1 is already excluded as an option. Each Team Project should be an independent entity with nothing shared between it. Since you have things shared, you've chosen the wrong organizational structure. Stop using multiple team projects.

Option 2 is okay, but it's a little bit clunkier.

Option 3 is the preferred, modern way of managing cross-project dependencies. I'd **strongly** recommend looking into implementing this pattern. If you adopt this pattern, maintaining multiple team projects becomes acceptable again -- you have one Team Project that acts as a publisher of shared components, and another that acts as a consumer. That's sufficiently isolated to consider them independent of one another, and thus an acceptable candidate for multiple Team Projects.

It's worth noting that the modern thought among most experts in this area is that maintaining a single Team Project for all related applications is the correct approach. I've seen teams with hundreds of members and dozens of applications using a single properly organized Team Project with no problems.

Comment: I actually did #1. We have old projects (with it's own sln) some of which are used in new projects in a new solution. I don't want to move all the old projects into new solution. We will move to #3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Daniel on the fact that this is probably a bad idea and that there are alternatives, it's perfectly possible; there's one restriction though: **each workspace must have its own copy of the shared project on your hard drive**, they can share the remote copy on the server. This si very similar to a distributed source control model and can work just fine.

To make this work, first create one workspace and map the folders locally:

```
 Workspace 1
 $/Common/           => c:\src\1stProject\Shared
 $/ProjectA/Solution => c:\src\1stProject\SolutionA
```

Then create a second workspace:

```
 Workspace 2
 $/Common/           => c:\src\2ndProject\Shared
 $/ProjectB/Solution => c:\src\2ndProject\SolutionB
```

This way both projects share the same server location and changes made to Shared will directly impact both SolutionA and SolutionB. Locally though, each solution will have its own local pending changes etc.

This solution will work as long as both Team Projects are in the same TFS Project Collection.

The only limitation is that these projects can't be placed in a subfolder of each other, so you can't do this:

```
 Workspace 1
 $/Common/           => c:\src\1stProject\SolutionA\Shared
 $/ProjectA/Solution => c:\src\1stProject\SolutionA
```

Nor can both workspaces map to the same local folder:

```
 Workspace 1
 $/Common/           => c:\src\Shared
 $/ProjectA/Solution => c:\src\1stProject\SolutionA

 Workspace 2
 $/Common/           => c:\src\Shared
 $/ProjectB/Solution => c:\src\1stProject\SolutionB
```

### Alternatives

**Nuget**

Instead of using shared sources directly, add a NuSpec to the Common project and build & publish the NuGet package to the VSTS package management feed of the VSTS account. Add a NuGet reference to SolutionA and to SolutionB. That way the binaries of Common are shared among SolutionA and SolutionB, but common is maintained independently. This way it's also easier to update SolutionA at a different cadence than SolutionB (this is also the biggest pitfall for this solution).

**Git & Submodules/Subtrees**

Convert the TFVC repositories to Git repositories. That way you can use Subtree or Submodules to reference Common directly from the SolutionA repository and the SolutionB repository.

**MonoRepo/One Project To Rule Them All**

Merge all your TFVC repositories into a single TFVC repository, that way both projects can easily live inside the same workspace. Technically this isn't needed to put both projects in the same workspace, but it is easier. It results in a very similar solution as described above:

```
 Workspace Single
 $/Project/Shared    => c:\src\Shared
 $/Project/SolutionA => c:\src\1stProject\SolutionA
 $/Project/SolutionB => c:\src\2ndProject\SolutionB
```

Would result in the same as the following cross-project layout:

```
 Workspace Single
 $/CommonProject/    => c:\src\Shared
 $/ProjectA/         => c:\src\1stProject\SolutionA
 $/ProjectB/         => c:\src\2ndProject\SolutionB
```

### Note

In any cross-project setup, the UI of both Visual Studio and VSTS will fight you. The VSTS team has been working on the ability to make individual Team Projects portable across accounts. In order to do that features like these will need to be dropped at some point. The UI in VSTS build, for example, will not show any other Team Projects in the Source picker. If you type the paths manually they will work (as long as you configure the build to have a Collection Level scope).

### Advice

The **Nuget** solution is the most reliable solution for the type of problem you're trying to solve. The VSTS Package Management feature will allow you to easily share the Common project across multiple projects and even across other VSTS accounts is you want to in the future. It's the most reliable solution.

If you need to be able to edit the files in either solution, I highly recommend you look into **Git Subtrees** or **Git Submodules**. Git is the future in any case and these features will allow you to achieve what you need in a much easier to sustain way. They do come with a steep learning curve though.

Comment: As both Daniel and you suggested, nuget package is a way to go.